# Magento custom pagination limit change

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I have create the custom pagination with Magento(1.9), see the below code for the pagination.

**code in block**

```
public function getPagerHtml()
 {
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
 }

protected function _prepareLayout()
 {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
  }
```

by default it list the first 5 list, i need to list only 4. how and where i need to work for this changes.

FYI i attached screen will better help you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `setAvailableLimit()` as

```
$pager->setAvailableLimit(array(4=>4,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all')); // Now you can get 4 items in a page.
```

> i.e, The first element in the array will be set the default limit for the
>   collection (per page).

Comment: Hi sundaram,i follow as per your suggestion, but still no response, unfortunately its show 6 records in first page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$pager->setPageSize(4)`